# Apache Derby - Syntax error: Encountered ";" at line 8, column 2

Tags: java, sql, syntax-error, derby, javadb

Making a small modular process in Java. However when i call the SQL statements from my website the system comes back with the error:

```
 java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered ";" at line 8, column 2.
```

Below is the first few lines of the SQL file in question as well as the system im using for retrieving the data.

SQL:

```
 CREATE TABLE "chat_logs"
 (
   "logId" BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
   "logDate" INT DEFAULT NULL,
   "logUser" BLOB,
   "logMessage" BLOB,
   PRIMARY KEY ("logId")
 );

 CREATE TABLE "configs"
 (
   "configId" BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
   "configType" BLOB,
   "configSettings" BLOB,
   PRIMARY KEY ("configId")
 );

 ...
```

Retrieval Script:

```
 InputStream in = new URL("http://db.*******.com/derby/version1.00.sql").openStream();
 return org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(in);
```

It does not make sense as to how a syntax error can be generated from a place where a semicolon is supposed to be.

Comment: *"It does not make sense as to how a syntax error can be generated from a place where a semicolon is supposed to be."* -  But it >>does<< make sense if the semicolon is not supposed to be there!

Comment: Try to post the query statement

Comment: If i post the statement as it is in RazorSQL or SQuirreL SQL it works fine.

Comment: Do i have to process each SQL statement individually?

Comment: If your code is trying to submit that SQL (the `CREATE` statements) using JDBC, then there should be one statement per JDBC `execute` and there should not be a semicolon after the `)`.

Comment: If you have a script full of SQL statements, and you want Derby to process those statements one-by-one, try this related question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30183734/how-to-open-a-command-prompt-and-input-different-commands-from-a-java-program/30197374#30197374  ... and see also this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042711/how-to-run-sql-scripts-in-order-to-update-a-derby-schema-from-java-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you'll need to split the string into individual statements and run each separately:

```
String[] createTableStatements = allStatements.Split...
for (String createStatement : createTableStatements) {
    try (Statement ps = connection.createStatement()) {
        ps.executeUpdate(createStatement);
    }
}
```