# Run the ij tool (Derby) from java

Tags: java, batch-file, derby, java-io

I try to run the *.bat files of derby, but I can't do this.

I want to run the "startNetworkServer.bat" and "ij.bat" using by java code.
I try to write some simple code but it not working.

```
package dbconnect;

import java.io.IOException;

public class RunDerbyTools {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String pathIj, pathStartNetwork, pathStopNetwork;

        pathIj = "C:/MyWorkSpace/MyDBProject/db/bin/ij.bat"; // running ij tool

        // running network
        pathStartNetwork = "C:/MyWorkSpace/MyDBProject/db/bin/startNetworkServer.bat";

        // stop network
        pathStopNetwork = "C:/MyWorkSpace/MyDBProject/db/bin/stopNetworkServer.bat";

        try {
            Process pStartNetwork = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pathStartNetwork);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Process pPathIj = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pathStartNetwork);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're looking for ij.runscript. See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6045550/193453